# Call to undefined function request_currencies()

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5.2.4

```
class ved_currencies extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
        ‘ved_currencies’,
        "Ved currencies",
        array( 'description' =>'Show currencies'));
    }

    private function request_currencies(){
        $date_req= time();
        $currencies = ["USD", "CNY", "EUR", "JPY", "BYN", "KZT", "UAH"];
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ){
        request_currencies(); // Line 30.
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Uncaught Error
: Call to undefined function request_currencies() in
C:\OSPanel\domains\ved\wp-content\plugins\ved-currencies\ved-currencies.php
on line
30
```

Line 30 is marked in the code example.

Could you help me understand why this error appeared?

Comment: Have you tried with this $this->request_currencies();

Comment: Thank you. Working. If you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this** keyword is used inside a class, generally withing the member functions to access non-static members of a class(variables or functions) for the current object.

```
class ved_currencies extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
        ‘ved_currencies’,
        "Ved currencies",
        array( 'description' =>'Show currencies'));
    }

    private function request_currencies(){
        $date_req= time();
        $currencies = ["USD", "CNY", "EUR", "JPY", "BYN", "KZT", "UAH"];
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ){
        $this->request_currencies(); // Line 30.
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

> I have call the function using  $this->request_currencies();

For your better understanding please visit this [link](https://www.studytonight.com/php/php-this-keyword)